# Using c# ternary operator to keep a variable the same

Tags: c#, optimization, conditional-operator, maintainability

I want to use the ternary operator to determine whether or not a variable should change.

The code looks as follows:

```
var c = "hello";
var appendWorld = false;
c = appendWorld ? string.Concat(c, " world") : c;
```

Since the value in case *appendWorld* is **false**, is the same as it was before, I was wondering if there's a more concise way of writing this code.

Please keep in mind that this is just a simplified example.

I want to be able to write something like this: `c = appendWorld ? string.Concat(c, " world");` where *c* automatically stays the same if *appendWorld* is **false**.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: why not use a good old `if` instead? Ternary means something like an if/else-appraoch. You seem to not have any else here.

Comment: If you must use ternary operator for some reason, it would probably have to be something like this: `c = string.Concat(c, appendWorld ? " world": "");` But I'd rather go with a simple `if`

Comment: The main reason for wanting to use a ternary operator is because of the long list of single **if**s that I currently have. It looks a lot better when replaced with one-liners. The only problem is that it is less efficient when I re-assign c to itself multiple times in a row.

Comment: Write a method which will contain if and action and call it. [Local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) are very convenient for this kind of things.

Comment: If ? is Syntactic sugar then It's a If/else and the c=c instruction will be a NOP in Clr. "No OPeration" It may not be revelant performance wise.

Comment: If you have a long list of single ifs, maybe you should refactor that code into some sort of design pattern or abstraction, instead of turning them into ternary operators to mitigate the complexity of the code.

Comment: The information that c=c will be a NOP is very valuable information, thank you. It basically means that it does what I want, without me removing the *: c* at the end.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution I think is to use an if condition

```
if(appendWorld)
   c = string.Concat(c, " world");
```